# How can I get the list packages I installed on my system?

Tags: package-management, system-installation

I'm looking for a way to determine which packages I have installed on my system *after* having installed the OS.

Say for example I install Xubuntu 16.04, which already comes with a certain number of packages. Then I setup all my work stuff and install a whole bunch of other packages.

Is there a way to list only the packages that I personally installed after my distribution was installed ?